# Trouble controlling vertical spacing for easylist

Tags: spacing, easylist

I am trying to get more control over the vertical spacing when using an [easylist](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf).

The MWE code below, gives me the following output. Two questions:

1. I'd like to reduce vertical spacing after each list. For example, I want the yellow highlighted part to be reduced.  Page 8 of the [documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/macros/latex/contrib/easylist/easylist-doc.pdf) contains info on a couple of `Space` parameters, but none seems to apply to the space *after* the list,
2. Why is there a relatively big space between the Title 3 and the first item in its list ('ee'), but *not* between the Title 1 and its list ('aaa')? To me, the relevant code looks exactly the same for both parts, but they render differently

[image]

**Minimum Working Example:**

```
\documentclass [a4paper,10pt] {article}
\usepackage[ampersand]{easylist}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\ListProperties(Hide=100, Hang=true, Progressive=1ex, Style*=$\bullet$ )

\begin{table}%
\begin{tabular}[b]{ l p{5cm}}
            \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{Bla bla bla}\\
            \midrule
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Title 1}}\\
                & \begin{easylist}
                    & aaaaa aaaa
                    & bb bbbb bbbb
                    \end{easylist} \\
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Title 2}}\\
                & Bla bla blaBla bla blaBla bla blaBla bla bla:\\
                 &  \begin{easylist}
                    & cccc ccc c 
                    & dd d ddd d
                    \end{easylist} \\
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Title 3}}\\
                 & \begin{easylist}
                    & ee eee ee
                    & ffff fff 
                    & ggggg ggg
                    \end{easylist} \\
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Title 4}}\\
                & Bla bla blaBla bla bla:
                    \begin{easylist}
                    & hh hhhhh 
                    & iii iii
                    \end{easylist} \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\caption{Example table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but the problem seems to be caused by your embedding the `easylst` into a `tabular` environment: if you take them out then all is fine. So your question is really how to make `easylst` and `tabular` how to play nicely together.

Comment: @Andrew: Following your finding, I've removed the tabular environment and it is working fine now. The table wasn't really necessary anymore, anyway...